# Infimum of an Infimum of a Function

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X:=\mathbb{R}^m$ and $Y:= \mathbb{R}^n$ be two sets and $f: X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ be a map over $X \times Y.$ I would like to show that
$$
\inf_{(\textbf{x},\textbf{y}) \in X \times Y} f(\textbf{x},\textbf{y}) = \inf_{\textbf{x} \in X} \widetilde{f}(\textbf{x})
$$
where
$$
\widetilde{f}(\textbf{x}) = \inf_{\textbf{y} \in Y} f(\textbf{x},\textbf{y}).
$$

Below is my attempt:
Begin by noting that
$
 \inf_{ (\textbf{x},\textbf{y}) \in X \times Y} f(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y}) \leq \inf_{\textbf{x} \in X} \widetilde{f}(\textbf{x}).
$
Hence, it reamins to show that the the reverse inequality also holds; i.e., we need to show $  \inf_{ (\textbf{x},\textbf{y}) \in X \times Y} f(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y}) \geq \inf_{\textbf{x} \in X} \widetilde{f}(\textbf{x})$. To this end, we  observe that
$$
f( \overline{\textbf{x}}, \overline{\textbf{y}}) \geq \inf_{\textbf{y} \in Y} f(\overline{\textbf{x}}, { \textbf{y} })
$$
for all $\overline{\textbf{x}} \in X, \overline{\textbf{y}} \in Y.$
Then take infimum over $X \times Y$ on both sides, we obtain
$$
\inf_{ (\textbf{x},\textbf{y}) \in X \times Y}f( {\textbf{x}}, {\textbf{y}}) \geq \inf_{ (\textbf{x},\textbf{y}) \in X \times Y} \widetilde{f}(\textbf{x}) = \inf_{\textbf{x} \in X} \widetilde{f}(\textbf{x})
$$
which is desired.

Does the proof look fine? or I am making some logical error here. Thank you.

Comment: The argument looks to be correct. Though as a matter of proper mathematical writing, you should introduce $\overline{\textbf{x}}$ and $\overline{\textbf{y}}$ before using them in a formula, rather than mentioning what they are after that formula (so introduce them with a 'let' statement and then give the formula).